# Liquibase / Spring Boot / Postgres - Schema name not working

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.2, Liquibase 3.5.5 and PostgreSQL 10.  I am able to successfully create a diff between the database and my JPA entities.  However, when I apply these changes to the database, it's applying the changes against the default "public" schema in PostgreSQL.  However, I want it to apply changes to a different schema, "dbo".

I tried multiple approaches to make it work without success.  I don't really want to edit each changeset and add a schema name manually.

Here is what I tried:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml</changeLogFile>
                    <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                    <defaultSchemaName>dbo</defaultSchemaName>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/FCV2Db?currentSchema=dbo</url>
                    <username>postgres</username>
                    <password>fastcode</password>
                    <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.nfinity.fastcode.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</referenceUrl>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <logging>debug</logging>
                    <dropFirst>false</dropFirst>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                        <version>3.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                        <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Yes, I tried to put the schema name as both a configuration property and on the JDBC Url connection as using either alone did not work.  Using both did not work either.

Anyone been successful in solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded to the latest version of PostgreSQL driver 42.2.5 and used the Url of the driver with ?currentSchema=schemaName and it worked.

Example: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/FCV2Db?currentSchema=dbo